# 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' (Centos, PHP 5.6)

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, centos

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /test2.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /test2.php(6): PDO->__construct('sqlite3:/var/ww...') #1 {main} thrown in /test2.php on line 6

Line 6

```
 $db = new PDO('sqlite3:' . $dir . '/db.sqlite');
```

Centos 7

PHP 5.6 (can change version in ISP-manager 5, but not work in all versions)

What to do? Thanks.

Comment: First of all, check which drivers are present: `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => sqlite )

Answer (score 0):

Try

`sudo yum install php56-pdo sqlite`

Or maybe

`sudo yum install php-sqlite`

I'm not quite sure (I don't have a CentOS server at the moment to test it on) but I'm sourcing from these answers [[1]](https://serverfault.com/questions/195790/how-do-i-activate-sqlite3-on-php-5-3-3-centos-5) [[2]](https://serverfault.com/questions/195790/how-do-i-activate-sqlite3-on-php-5-3-3-centos-5)

Comment: Pack called php56 - PDO not found.
SQLite package - 3.7.17-8.el7.x86_64 already installed , and is the latest version .
perform nothing

Comment: Did you try the second one? Try installing `php-sqlite`

Comment: Not found too. Maybe need another repo?